# Accessing an object created by one view controller from another view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Is there a way to create an `NSObject` and set values for it in one view controller, and get them back in another view controller by looking for the existing instance of that `NSObject`?

Much like AppDelegate has its `sharedInstance` that you can access from anywhere and thus put values into it from anywhere?

I created a view controller that instantiates my model object and fills its properties.  How do I access that instance of the model object from another view controller?

I'm not asking how to pass data in a view controller that calls another view controller.  I know how to do that.  I'm asking how to set values to a model object from different, unrelated and hierarchically independent view controllers.

Comment: All those examples pass data to and from VC.  I'm capturing data in a vc but trying to store it in a custom NSObject.

Comment: Passing, storing; it's the same thing.

Comment: Oh, what I meant is, I'm in a tabbar controller, so there is no sequence from one vc to another.  I wish to receive data in a tab and have it available in another tab.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, what you are looking for is [Key Value Observation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).  It is commonly used to decouple the controller layer from the model layer (as in MVC, Model View Controller).